# Dynamic Javascript Table script does not work on every row

Tags: javascript, html

I had done some research on how to add rows as needed by the user and had great success with a tiny script. The issue im encountering is that when a new row is created the check boxes that i use to copy data from one field to another no longer work on any row except the first row. Im sure i have to be missing something obvious as im new to the web scene and unsure what tool i should use to get the job done(Doing a lot of trial and error). Aside from that if there is a better way to accomplish this im open to something new or a link to a similar issue that would help me solve my issue. Collecting the data isnt an issue so my guess is im missing some scripting

```
@model Guru.SubscriptionDb.Models.CreateMultiProduct
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Product";
}
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/brandonStyles.css" type="text/css" />
    <title>Create Product</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addRow() {            
            $("#formTable tbody tr:first").clone().find("input").each(function () {
                $(this).val('');
            }).end().appendTo("#formTable");
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        function calc()
        {
            var amount = $("#Annual").val();
            document.getElementById('Fee1').value = amount;
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        function calc2() {
                var amount = $("#Annual").val();
                document.getElementById('Fee2').value = amount;
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <a style="margin: 10px 0;" href="javascript:addRow();">Add New Record</a>
        <table id="formTable" class="DataTable" border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Annual Fee</th>
                    <th>Fee 1</th>
                    <th>Fee 2</th>
                    <th>Fee 3</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Annual" id="Annual" style="width: 100px;" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Fee1" id="Fee1" style="width: 100px;" /> <div style="font-size:x-small">Same as Annual  <input type="checkbox"  id="SameAsAnnual"  onchange="calc()" ; /></div></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Fee2" id="Fee2" style="width: 100px;" /> <div style="font-size:x-small">Same as Annual  <input type="checkbox"  id="SameAsAnnual2" onchange="calc2()" ;> </div></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="imp" style="width: 100px;" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: You're copying an entire row of elements, but that includes their IDs. IDs should be *unique*, not only because of HTML specifications, but because your `getElementById` can only return **one element**. It will always return the **first** occurrence of that ID, which is why your first row is the only one working. You should use classes instead, and familiarize with jQuery's [class selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

Comment: Thank you ill take a look into this